Consider the circuit shown in (Figure 1). Suppose that R = 20 ohms. Find the thevenin equivalent

Consider the circuit shown in (Figure 1). Suppose that R
= 20 Ω Find the Thevenin equivalent.
I got an answer of 4.6 Ω and 18 V for Rth and Vth but the correct answer is 5 Ω and 12 V.

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Find the thevenin equivalent given R = 20 ohms

that is not a question ... it is a description of a problem to be solved ... please show your work so that people can see where your thinking needs to change

so for the Rth since the 20 and 6 ohm resistors are in parallel I did 20*6/(20+6) and I got 4.6 ohms

please edit the question ... comments are not for adding info

Where did you get the "correct answer" from?  I got -11.25V and 4.875ohm.  The current source pointing down makes it so voltage from A to B is negative.

The "correct answer" is not correct (it would be correct for a certain different (and integer) value of R, so maybe something got mixed up in the quiz).
But your approach is not correct either.
Please review the procedure for calculating Rth to start with, and draw out the schematic if it helps.
